# create an angular regex filter

Tags: angularjs, regex, angularjs-filter

I am trying to create an Angular filter to provide regex functionality. I am consuming the flickr API - [see example here](https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tagmode=all&format=json) and one key value of the json object returned is

```
{......
   "author": "nobody@flickr.com (John Doe)"
....}
```

Currently, this is my **filter** regex function:

```
app.filter('regex', function() {
    return function(input, regex) {
        return input.match(regex);  
    }
})
```

and in my **html** I have this

```
<p>{{user.author | regex:'(/\((.*?))\)/g)'}}</p>
```

and the filter is injected into the **controller**, which looks like this

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function ($http, regexFilter) {
      //do controller stuff!
}
```

I am looking to isolate just the user's name and drop the `nobody@flickr.com` so that `John Doe` is returned

Any guidance on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try adding a filter like this

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.filter('regex', function() {
   return function(val){
     var RegExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
     var match = RegExp.exec(val);
     return match[1];
   };
});
myApp.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.user = {'author': "nobody@flickr.com (John Doe)"};
});
```

Working JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WfuAh/147/

Comment: BOOM! That worked, thank you! You can use it in the html also like this
`<p>{{user.author | regex}}</p>`